# Tests folder not found when test zip package is built programmatically in .NET

Tags: amazon-web-services, zip, aws-device-farm

I'm working with AWS Appium for Python. Due to our project requirements, the test will be in Python, but we need to use .NET to programmatically build, upload, and schedule the test in AWS.

Following AWS documentation, the test package zip file should have the following items in its root directory: "tests" folder, "wheelhouse" folder, and "requirements.txt" file.

When I manually build the package on a Windows machine (simply select the files and folders, right click, and add to the zip archive), the package is accepted by AWS and the test runs correctly.

However, when I build the package programmatically in .NET, even though the output zip file has the same folder structure as the manually built zip file, AWS rejects it with this error message:

**"We could not find the tests directory in the *root* of your test package"**

I have tried 3 different ways to build the package programmatically in .NET. Both methods lead to the same error. Briefly, the methods are as follows:

1/ Create a "TestPackage" folder containing the "tests" folder, "wheelhouse" folder, and "requirements.txt" file. Use the following code to zip the entire TestPackage folder:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("TestPackage", zipPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, includeBaseDirectory: false);
```

The `includeBaseDirectory` flag is set to `false` so that all of the folders and file will be in the root directory of the zip file.

2/ Create an empty zip file. Then add all files ("requirements.txt" and all the files in the folders), to the zip file using the pseudo code below:

```
using (var zipStream = File.Create(zipPath))
{
  using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
  {
    // entryName is the relative path to the file
    // For eg., a file in the tests folder will have this path:
    // @"\tests\test_sample.py"
    zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(sourceFileName, entryName)
  }
}
```

3/ Use the following PowerShell script:

```
# Get the path to the AWSDeviceTests folder
# Assumption: the script file is in this folder
$ProjectDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# Get the paths of the test folders and file
$RequirementsFileDir = Join-Path -Path $ProjectDir -ChildPath "requirements.txt"
$TestsFolderDir = Join-Path -Path $ProjectDir -ChildPath "tests"
$WheelhouseFolderDir = Join-Path -Path $ProjectDir -ChildPath "wheelhouse"

# Zip the test folders and file
$ZipDestination = Join-Path -Path $ProjectDir -ChildPath "TestPackage.zip"
Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $RequirementsFileDir, $TestsFolderDir, $WheelhouseFolderDir -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath $ZipDestination
```

All of the methods above have failed. `ZipFile` and `ZipArchive` come from `System.IO.Compression` in .NET.

I want to stress once again that the output zip files of all methods have the exact same folder structure as the zip file that I build manually, i.e. all of the required folders and file are in the root directory of the zip file. While the manually built file works, the programmatically built files don't.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a known problem building AWS device test packages in .NET or Windows? Or is it not possible to programmatically build and upload test packages to AWS Device Farm? How exactly is the zip file parsed/validated in AWS Device Farm?

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had a similar issue once with the archiver in a Mac.  In that situation I found that if I  didn't delete the zip before hand that the zip would not update.  So I had to delete it first and then zip everything up again.  

Not sure if that&amp;#39;s what&amp;#39;s happening here but I hope that helps.  Sounds like a very granular problem with .NET SDK.

Comment: @jmp Thanks for the suggestion. In my code, I did check if the zip file already existed, and if it did, I would delete it before creating a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I noticed something interesting. Each time I built the zip file manually, I was doing so using 7zip: select the file and folders => right click => 7zip => Add to "archiveName.zip"

In contrast, in all of the methods that I used to automate the build process, I was using what appeared to be Windows built-in zip functionality (whatever that is; WinZip maybe??).

So I decided to try again but using 7zip in my code, and it worked. Below is the code:

```
// Execute command line to zip the build file and folder using 7-zip
// Assumption: 7zip.exe is installed in this directory
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip");
string sevenZipExecutable = @"7z.exe";
string requirementsFile = projectDirectory + @"\requirements.txt";
string testsFolder = projectDirectory + @"\tests";
string wheelhouseFolder = projectDirectory + @"\wheelhouse";
string arguments = $"/C {sevenZipExecutable} a -tzip \"{zipPath}\" \"{requirementsFile}\" \"{testsFolder}\" \"{wheelhouseFolder}\"";
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

From this, I guess the problem must be the result of some obscure difference between how 7zip and Windows built-in zip build zip files. I suppose my "answer" does not really explain how or why this occurred, but at least now there's a working solution for others who might run into this problem.